# Streamreader.ReadAsync() stops reading data from persistent network stream

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am attempting to read the output of an IP phone system. My current implementation is using Streamreader.ReadAsync() to read a single char at a time from the stream into a result string, and then when I hit the custom line terminator provided by the phone system I am parsing the result string and storing the data. Here is a sample:

```
using (var monitor = new TcpClient(ip, port))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(monitor.GetStream()))
                {
                    var streamChar = new char[1];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        await reader.ReadAsync(streamChar, 0, streamChar.Length);
```

What I am finding is that this implementation works properly during the day, but soon after 5PM I stop logging data. I am spitting out the read content to a file and I see no difference in the raw data provided at the time that logging ceases. When the ReadAsync() method hangs, I still see an open socket using netstat. I tested tonight and confirmed that if I simply allow the app to create a new TcpClient connecting to the same source within the same instance of the logging application, it begins receiving data normally.

I have previously tried using reader.EndOfStream and reader.Peek() to determine when to read the next char, but switched to this implementation because my understanding is that EndOfStream and Peek are blocking operations. I had seen the app hang at these conditionals, so I got rid of them and replaced them with what you see based on the understanding that this IP phone system will perpetually send data when new calls are received.

I am reaching out to see if anyone can confirm whether my implementation is flawed or whether I need to start focusing more on the phone system itself. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess your connection times out. You need to check for that. You can set a timeout on the TcpClient: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout.aspx

Comment: BTW: I draw my conclusion from: During the day it works fine, the phone application frequently sends messages. "Soon after 5 PM" - I guess there won't be many phone calls or maybe they are automatically redirected to a recorded "you are calling out of hours" message that doesn't produce output where you are listening. Since you don't seem to send anything over the line, read won't detect tear down of the TCP connection while waiting for input. To know a reasonable timeout, you should look up the API docs to see if there is something about timeouts. I'd make it configurable in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! The system I am working with has no API, but I am going to work off of your recommendation as best I can anyway and try to compensate for a potential timeout. I added something to periodically write a single byte back to the endpoint to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to compensate for the timeout by writing back a single byte to the endpoint at a periodic interval. This resolved the issue and the connection is now remaining open. I had to deal with the response provided by the endpoint, but it would only reply with old call data that I simply discard.